# .net core mvc routing and controllers

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

So I am brand new to .net. I am learning .net core right now. I am trying to figure out routing. I can not seem to get the routing to look in any folder except Home and Shared.  I have looked all over the internet and tried many things. There seems to be something I am missing. Here is what I got

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "test", 
                    template: "Register/test",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Register", action = "test"}
                    );

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            });
```

I have a Register folder with a test.cshtml file in just to try t figure this routing out. And this is is in my HomeController.cs file

```
        public IActionResult test()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

on my _Layout page I have this link

```
  <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Register" asp-action="test">Test</a></li>
```

It works fine when I put it in the home folder, but I want to keep things separate. I know there is something I am missing. I've poured through all kinds on articles online including Stack Overflow, and I just don't understand what I am missing. From what I read its suppose to be like the Parent folder/File/ then and id that may be attached to that like a user name I have tried other formats for the routing with no luck, this was just my most recent attempt. I just can't help but think I need some bit of code somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry ! What is the real problem you are facing ? What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: Adding routes to a navbar, right now, because that seems to be the easiest instance of routing, but i guess not for me. Basically the link should go to the test page in the Register folder.

Comment: Well I did get it to work. Not sure what I did different than what I have tried before. Which doesn't really help me to understand it better. But now that I got it working maybe i can dissect it better to see.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like you have the following code in your `HomeController`.

```
public IActionResult test()
{
    return View();
}
```

That actually belongs in your `RegisterController` because the route template you defined is an explicit capture with defaults to the "Register" controller and the "test" action.

The view called "test.cshtml" - which should be named as such because of the default convention - should reside in your `\Views\Register` folder, next door to `\Views\Home`.

There are a couple of reasons why this may have worked in some fashion. First, the view is discoverable for any controller if it's in shared. Without knowing more about the requests you tried, it's difficult to determine if routing kicked in on the first route or second, but if that method was truly on `HomeController` requests to /home/test would have worked.

It looks to me like you're exploring routing. That is great - I 100% encourage the experimentation - so long as you know that routing isn't necessarily the lowest hanging fruit to learn. It's also something that you shouldn't have to touch 93.7% of the time.  For example, the route you have defined about wouldn't be required for the controller and action you're adding with `RegisterController` and `test`.

Cheers.